# Jquery... Cell text not re-displaying after I click on another table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table.  It displays data from MySQL via PHP

I am using jquery to dynamically obtain data from users.

When users click on a cell:
1.the cell text displays 'none'
2.the check box in the cell is checked

### 3.an input text field to appear for user input

when users click off of the cell (eg. to another cell) I want:
1.the check box to uncheck itself
2.the input text field to disappear
3.and the cell text to re-display

I have all of them working except 3.the cell text to re-display.
I need the original text of the cell to display when the user clicks another cell

```
           $('#table9 tr td').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

    //checks checkbox of cell by default
    $this.children('input').prop('checked', true);

    //makes sure that checkboxes in other cells are not checked
    $this.siblings().children('input').prop('checked', false);
    $this.parent('tr').siblings().children('td').children('input').prop('checked', false);

    //hides current text in cell if cell is clicked
    $('span' , this).css('display','none');



    //displays a text field for input
    $this.children('.hiddenjqside').css('display' , 'inline');

    //hides input text field if user should click on another cell
    $this.siblings().children('.hiddenjqside').css('display' , 'none');
    $this.parent('tr').siblings().children('td').children('.hiddenjqside').css('display', 'none');


    //display the text of the current cell when user click another cell
    $('span' , this).siblings().css('display' , 'inline'); <---------NOT WORKING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do:

```
$this.siblings().find('span').css('display' , 'inline');
```

Or using context:

```
$('span' , $this.siblings()).css('display' , 'inline');
```

Also you can save yourself some typing by using [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) instead of manually changing the css `display` property

Comment: Or [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of manually typing out `hide()` and `show()`.

Comment: @DavidThomas I gather OP wants to toggle elements that were previously hidden by a click event, using `toggle()` in this case would act upon all elements causing unwanted behavior (in my mind) unless a visibility selector is used

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out... I might have not stated the questions clearly.  Below is what I did.

```
$this.siblings().children('span').css('display' , 'inline');
    $this.parent('tr').siblings().children('td').children('span').css('display' ,       'inline');
```